# Are there 3 definitions of rectangular numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers

I'm a little bit confused about the definition on **rectangular numbers**, which is also giving me doubts about its function (or idea).

1. So there's the definition of that all rectangular can be found
   with this formula: **$$ f(n) = (n-1) \cdot (n+4) $$** We get: **0, 6, 14, 24,
   36, 50**.
2. Others define it as the double of triangular numbers:
   **$$ f(n) = n \cdot (n+1) $$** Then we get: **0, 2, 6, 12, 20**
3. There are also numbers that are **neither primes nor squares**,
   like: **8, 10, 16, 18, 22**. These numbers can be graphically displayed
       as rectangles of dots. Or do we call these composite numbers?

So I'm a little bit confused here. I'm also very interested in what their uses are. Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: I don't think "rectangular numbers" is in standard use...largely because of the proliferation of definitions (that you have noticed).  My guess is that, if you used it without clear context, "most" people would guess that you meant [Pronic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronic_number), your second definition.  But when a term is as ambiguous as this one is I'd say you should either avoid using it (my choice) or, if you do use it, clearly state which definition you intend.